# Is there any Menu Module to show thumb image, content tile when mouse over on menu item

Tags: routes

I want to create a main menu bar for my drupal blog, like shown in image

> [image]

Means, when i mouse over on the menu item, it should show, node thumb image, content title.

is there any modules available to do this. I tried in google to find like this modules, no luck. Please any one give suggestion how to do this.

Comment: try this https://drupal.org/project/menuimage

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) Module and [MaxiMenu](https://drupal.org/project/maximenu).

Edit: you might also need the [Menu Views Module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_views) and potentially [Nice Menus Module](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) to achieve the perfect style you want.

I have not tested this but a Coworker built a client's dropdown menu with images this way, So i know it is possible. I just personally haven't done it =-)

I hope this gets you close!

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the [Menu Minipanels](https://drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels) module:

> A system for building "megamenu" -style (explanation) dropdown menus using Mini Panels, which provides tremendous flexibility in what can be displayed.
>   ...
>   There are two main reasons why minipanels are used:
>
> 1. Usability: once an initial learning curve is gotten past the module becomes very easy to use.
> 2. Flexibility: there is a tremendous amount of configuration available via minipanels and almost anything can be added to one - views, blocks, nodes, other menus, and even raw PHP code if the PHP Filter is enabled. Further, there are multiple layouts available and more can be easily built. Further, each minipanel can be customized differently, as can be seen from some of the example sites below.

Comment: can you expand a bit more, otherwise it will consider as link only answer

Comment: You can create a mini panel and attach it to any menu item. It works the same way Panels module work.

Comment: OP asked about how to attach image item in submenu, but how to add the image using the module you mentioned ? meaning how it is related ? and the downvote is not from me, please make it clear while answering the question, thanks

Comment: It is my first post on this site. I believe that if he will go to the link he will find much better information than my explanation especially with my very bad English. I realy don't care about the downvote, I'll continue answer to posts here as much I know. Thanks!

Comment: roni your welcome to post more ,  please never stop, thanks.